# Replace string in all file names in current folder and subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I've been searching in forum but couldnt find the solution to my needs.
I have the following code to replace a defined string in filesname by extension. It is possible to change it to make the search in the current folder and subfolders please?

```
@echo off
Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Set "Pattern=3688"
Set "Replace=0000"

For %%a in (*.txt) Do (
    Set "File=%%~a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would make more sense, if you only loop through the ones containing your `Pattern`, instead of all of them, and only enabling delayed expansion, when needed.

Here's a complete example to show you:

```batch-file
@Set "Pattern=3688"
@Set "Replace=0000"

@For /R %%G In ("*%Pattern%*.txt") Do @(Set "BaseName=%%~nG"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Ren "%%G" "!BaseName:%Pattern%=%Replace%!%%~xG"
    EndLocal)
```

*Please note however that **this will not work with any string** of characters defined as `Pattern` or `Replace`.*

Answer (score 1):

You're close. Use `for` switch `/R` (for Recursive) and adapt to `Set "File=%%~nxa"` (because the second argument for `ren` does support a filename only - no path information)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Set "Pattern=3688"
Set "Replace=0000"

For /R %%a in (*.txt) Do (
    Set "File=%%~nxa"
    ECHO Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer :) but I cannot make it work... Could you please try? Sorry..

Comment: what does it do? (you noticed, I "disarmed" the `ren` command by just echoing it?)